# If $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ then $f(M)$ is a maximal subgroup of $f(G)$?

Tags: group-theory

I need to prove the following:

> If $M <_{\operatorname{max}} G$ and $f:G \to H$ is a homomorphism such
>   that $\operatorname{ker}(f) \subseteq M$, then $f(M) <_{\operatorname{max}} f(G)$.

I was thinking that if $f(M)$ were not a maximal subgroup, then there would be a proper subgroup of $f(G)$ that is properly containing it, say $f(K)$. But then I'm not sure if I can say that $M$ is a properly contained in $K$. This can't be right because I'm not even using the condition that $\operatorname{ker}(f) \subseteq M$ anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume as you said that there is a proper subgroup $\tilde K$ of $f(G)$ containing $f(M)$. Then, I claim that $K:= f^{-1}(\tilde K)$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ which contains $M$. If we had $K=G$, then it immediately follows that $f(G)=f(K)=f(f^{-1}(\tilde K))\subseteq\tilde K$, implying that $\tilde K$ is not proper. So we are left to show that $M\subseteq K$. Indeed, here you require that $\ker(f)\subseteq M$. From $f(M)\subseteq \tilde K$ we ge that $f^{-1}(f(M))\subseteq K$. I claim that $f^{-1}(f(M))=M$. Indeed, we only need to show "$\subseteq$", so let $g\in G$ be such that $f(g)\in f(M)$. In oher words, there is some $m\in M$ with $f(g)=f(m)$, i.e. $f(gm^{-1})=1$, ergo $gm^{-1}\in\ker(f)\subseteq M$. Thus, $g\in M$ and we are done.